# Logitech Z906 Not Working Properly

Tags: logitech, 23.10, pipewire

I bought the Logitech Z906 5.1 Speaker System

[image]

And after connecting all the cables to each speaker and setting Ubuntu 23.10 to HiFi 5.1 Channels, there are 2 issues (One that I can look away or might be my ignorance)

1. The bigger issue is that when testing each individual Speaker, the Rear Left does not produce any sound. I changed the speaker with another one that works and all good. I even changed and double checked the cable, all good there. The 2 Front ones work, the center one works and the Rear Left also produces sound when clicking on the little speaker icons on the test as shown in the image below. I did however check alsamixer and I see there is a PCM1 and PCM2. The PCM1 by default is disabled (Do not know if it is related) but disabling it or enabling does nothing, and there is the PCM2 which basically looks like the image below:

[image]

2. The other issue and pardon my sound audiophile ignorance, when I ONLY connect each individual front speaker and test with the Ubuntu system each speaker, each one works perfectly. When testing the rear ones, it looks like they REQUIRE the center one to be connected to or else they will not make any sound.

The Sound system is connected to an Asus Z790 Hero motherboard which has the following Audio device integrated:

```
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7a50] (rev 11)
```